# Terraform fails to actually set beanstalk tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have a pre-existing beanstalk, and we need to set tags on it.  I modified the Terraform plan to have said tags. When I run Terraform plan, it says it will "update in place". Yay?

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  ~ module.beanstalk_postal-service.aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.beanstalk

tags.%:           "0" => "4"
tags.component:   "" => "postal-service"
tags.extra_type:  "" => "none"
tags.stack_type:  "" => "ups"
tags.virtual_env: "" => "stage"
Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

When I run the plan it says everything went OK and shows tags being set.

```
module.beanstalk_postal-service.aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.beanstalk: 
Modifying... (ID: e-mz7xa7jga8)
tags.%:           "0" => "4"
tags.component:   "" => "postal-service"
tags.extra_type:  "" => "none"
tags.stack_type:  "" => "ups"
tags.virtual_env: "" => "stage"
module.beanstalk_postal-service.aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.beanstalk: 
Modifications complete after 3s (ID: e-mz7xa7jga8)
```

If I run the plan again,  after applying, it shows no changes, indicating the tags must be set.

When I go into the AWS Console, however,  the tags do not appear on the beanstalk.  Some tags I set yesterday through Terraform and passed plan, showed up as needing to be set again today.   Anybody know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

It may sound trivial, but.. you just can't edit or add tags to the existing EBS environments. With that said, there might be some issue in terraform as it should inform you that you can't do this, but instead it gives you false positive at the end.

The easiest way to have tags on the environment you already have is to "clone" it and set tags in there.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of,   but thanks for confirming.

Comment: @StivOstenberg there's a light in the end of the tunnel we're in. Check this out https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/10/aws-elastic-beanstalk-supports-ability-to-update-tags/ They added that recently